# [javascript]Variable not receiving values when I include Enter

Tags: javascript

I was trying to edit a js document .I searched on internet for hours but I couldn't find solution. 
`var entry = " Hi . This is a new paragraph ";`

When I include a ENTER before " This is a new paragraph " it shows error or nothing. So I want entry variable receives texts with enter.

I'm a newbie in JavaScript . The above code just looks similar to C++. Maybe Enter is a termination character .
Is there an way to do that ? Or please give a sample script to remove Enter characters in a text file ( I don't need a ruby or python script, an exe file is better for me)

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not allow multi line strings (except in es6)

You would need to do:

```
var entry = 'Hi ' +
'This is a new paragraph';
```

If you wanted to add a new line character:

```
var entry = 'Hi \n' +
'This is a new paragraph';
```

Or, to keep the expression all on one line:

```
var entry = 'Hi \nThis is a new paragraph' ;
```

Comment: It feels c++ . Thank you for the answer

Comment: Why a new line for a new line: var newline = 'Hi,\nthis is a newline'; I agree, less readable, but \n for newline is enough.